# Mocking Orchard dynamic types with Moq

Tags: dynamic, moq, orchardcms

I'm wondering whether anyone has any advice about effective ways to mock some of the Clay functionality in Orchard? I've gone as far as creating a wrapper interface, `IClayWrapper`, which I wrap around some of the more convoluted dynamic calls. Unfortunately, these wrapper methods need to return dynamic objects, so I'm still having problems. Here's a small example:

```
public interface IClayWrapper : IDependency
{
    dynamic BuildClipCreateViewModel(string projectTitle, string moduleTitle, dynamic clipForm);
}

public class WhenViewingCreateClip : GivenAClipController
{
    private IEnumerable<ContentItem> queryResults;

    protected override ClipController Establish_context()
    {
        var queryResults = new List<ContentItem>
        {
            new ContentItem(),
            new ContentItem(),
        };
        ClayWrapperMock.Setup(x => x.BuildLookupListFromQuery(queryResults, "Create")).Returns(It.IsAny<dynamic>());
    }
}
```

The problem I'm currently facing is that Moq returns this error:

> SetUp : Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : '`Moq.Language.Flow.ISetup<Aqovia.Module.MotionGallery.Infrastructure.IClayWrapper,object>`' does not contain a definition for '`Returns`'

Basically, it's changed the `Returns` method from Moq into a dynamic call, which is one of the main issues that I was facing with the Clay stuff before I tried wrapping it. I've also tried introducing a fake shape factory with similar results. Has anyone found an effective way to test this stuff? Other than don't test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the point? Mocking a dynamic object is absurd, as you can build them much more easily than a mock, which is why there are typically no mocking frameworks in dynamic languages: you don't need them. Just use a real Clay object.

You may also want to know that Clay will not ship with Orchard 1.7.

Comment: It's probably that I don't understand enough about how Clay works. How can I control which Clay objects the Clay Factory returns in the production code from within my test code?

Comment: Great question. In most situations, using the DefaultShapeFactory should work just fine. If you need a different collection of behaviors, the ShapeTests class gives a great example of handling shape factory events to add a custom behavior on creation that is pretty much the equivalent of mocking.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Bertrand, I'll check it out

Comment: It works! The issue I had was that I was returning an instance of a ClayFactory from IOrchardServices.New rather than using Autofac to give me a DefaultShapeFactory via IoC. Once I'd made that change the test went green. Thanks Bertrand, we've been wrestling with this issue for weeks.